# I want to login to an application from different browsers using different username and password

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to login my application with different username and password on different and same browser in selenium webdriver using java and testNg, right now I can login only with one username and password and with one browser only. If I change the browser name in config file then only my test run to that particular browser, I want my application running on different browser with same or different username and password. My framework structure is:

1.pkg1  -  contains Driver class
2.pkg2  -  contains all utilities
3.pkg3  -  contains all locators of web page
4.pkg4  -  contains all methods
5.pkg5  -  contains tests

Comment: This will help you: http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-factory-design-pattern-using-java-8-supplier/

Comment: I didnt find this useful

Comment: @jay - Edit your question and add code snippets of what you have tried so far, and where you are stuck and need help.